Standard matrix for linear transformation
Let $A\in M_{m,n}$,$B\in M_{m',n'}$ and define a linear map
\begin{align*}
& L : \mathbb{R}^n\oplus \mathbb{R}^{n'} \to \mathbb{R}^m\oplus\mathbb{R}^{m'} \\
& \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x} \\ \boldsymbol{y} \end{bmatrix}\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}  A\boldsymbol{x}  \\ B\boldsymbol{y} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
The question is to find the standrad matrix for L relative to the standard bases. My attempt on the question goes as folows. Let
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B} = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_1 & \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}^T, ... , \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_n & \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}^T , 
\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{f}_1 \end{bmatrix}^T, ... , \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{f}_{n'}
\end{bmatrix}^T\right\}, \quad \boldsymbol{e}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 & ... & 0\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}
be the basis for $\mathbb{R}^n\oplus \mathbb{R}^{n'}$ and let
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C} = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_1 & \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}^T, ... , \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_m & \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}^T , 
\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{f}_1 \end{bmatrix}^T, ... , \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{f}_{m'} \end{bmatrix}^T\right\}, \quad \boldsymbol{f}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 & ... & 0\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}
be the basis for $\mathbb{R}^m\oplus\mathbb{R}^{m'}$. Then we get that:
\begin{align*}
& L\left(\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_i \\  \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}  A\boldsymbol{e}_i  \\ B\boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix} \\
& = \left\{A = [\boldsymbol{v}_1 ...\boldsymbol{v}_n ]\right\} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{v}_i \\  \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix} \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^ma_{ji}\boldsymbol{e}_j \implies \\
& \left[L\left(\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{e}_i \\  \boldsymbol{0} \end{bmatrix}\right) \right]_{\mathcal{B}} =  \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,i} & a_{2,i} & ... & a_{m,i} & 0 & ... & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T, \quad i = 1,...,n
\end{align*}
Doing the same for $L\left(\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} \\  \boldsymbol{f}_i \end{bmatrix}\right)$  gives that the standard matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} A & 0_m \\
0_{m'} & B \end{bmatrix}$, where $0_m\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n'}$ and $0_{m'}\in \mathbb{R}^{m'\times n}$ are full of zeros.
My questions are: 
(1) Are the bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ correct?
(2) What is the correct notation for the matrix? Is it supposed to be $[L]_{\mathcal{C}\mathcal{B}}$ or $[L]_{\mathcal{C}\mathcal{C}}$ (or something else?)
(3) Is the $\oplus$ a inner or outer direct sum? How can i determine it?
